Unexpected semicolon in array expression when initializing Julia matrix
I am trying to create and initialize a matrix in Julia using the initialization syntax, which as far as I am aware allows the programmer to use a comma , to separate values along the first dimension, and semicolons ; to separate values along the second dimension.
I would have expected the following to work, but it did not. (Error below.)
m::Matrix{Int8} = [
        3,9,1,2,8,6,5,7,4;
        4,8,7,3,5,9,1,2,6;
        6,5,2,7,1,4,8,3,9;
        8,7,5,4,3,1,6,9,2;
        2,1,3,9,6,7,4,8,5;
        9,6,4,5,2,8,7,1,3;
        1,4,9,6,7,3,2,5,8;
        5,3,8,6,7,3,2,5,8;
        7,2,6,8,9,5,3,4,1;
    ]

ERROR: LoadError: syntax: unexpected semicolon in array expression around /home/user/julia/dir/test/test_container.jl:67

What mistake have I made here?

Julia arrays basically have three separate syntaxes, although with whitespace you can make these a lot hairier:

Just use commas. This gets you a 1D vector.
Use spaces and semicolons. This gets you a 2D matrix whose rows are the semicolon-separated items (so that space-separated items are not adjacent in memory, but when formatted correctly the input looks like the 2D matrix it corresponds to).
(Newish) Use only semicolons. The more consecutive semicolons, the weaker they bind (fewer consecutive semicolons → closer together in memory). For a 2D matrix, this produces the transpose of what's produced in #2.

julia> [1,2,3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> [1; 2;; 3; 4;;; 5; 6;; 7; 8]
2×2×2 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8


Maybe worth adding that method 1 constructs a vector, while 2,3 concatenate. Thus if a=[1,2]; b=[3,4]; c=[5,6], then [a,b,c] isa Vector{<:Vector} of length 3, while [a;b;c] isa Vector{Int} of length 6. When a,b,c are numbers this distinction doesn't matter.

I find it very strange that this worked.
board_matrix::Matrix{Int8} = [
    3 9 1 2 8 6 5 7 4;
    4 8 7 3 5 9 1 2 6;
    6 5 2 7 1 4 8 3 9;
    8 7 5 4 3 1 6 9 2;
    2 1 3 9 6 7 4 8 5;
    9 6 4 5 2 8 7 1 3;
    1 4 9 6 7 3 2 5 8;
    5 3 8 6 7 3 2 5 8;
    7 2 6 8 9 5 3 4 1;
]

Apparently spaces are separators rather than commas. This is highly unusual as most languages ignore whitespace, or if whitespace is significant it is used only for defining indentation (which really defines scope).

This is the same as in Matlab, which was an inspiration for Julia array syntax. Since matrices are very commonly used in Julia (as in Matlab) it was given a convenient literal construction syntax. After the introduction of the general Nd-array syntax using ;, ;;, ;;; etc. the totality of syntax has become a bit crowded, but it's hard to change at this point. Also, the syntax in your post is so widespread and popular, removing it would be highly unpopular.

@DNF right I see - it must be somewhat hard to read if the data (the numbers) are all different widths when encoded as strings? I know in this case I have integers from 1 to 9, but that just happens to be the case as I'm playing around with a Sudoku board. In many cases you might have grids of floating point values, for example.

I guess it's rare that one wants large literal matrices with literal numerical values. If you do, you would have to set them up with nice spacing/alignment etc. But I don't think it would be much nicer with any other literal constructor syntax, anyway.
